# Google maps and data storage

Tags: google-maps, geospatial, bing-maps, bigdata

I don't have good understanding of Big data libraries/spatial data. Can someone help to demystify how google maps, bing maps (any maps) store data internally? If I want a Image at some latitude 'x' and some longitude 'y' at some zoom factor, how is this data stored for efficient retrieval? Also, there is quite a bit of information associated at every point in cell, how is this data stored? Links to relevant pages or blogs will be of great help.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Most highly scalable map providers start out with the spatial data stored in a spatial database, including road lines, rail lines, polygonal boundaries, hydrography, etc. However, they don't render the maps directly from that data for every user request because that would take far too long for the millions of requests they get every day.

Instead, tiles of the maps are rendered offline using the spatial data, and stored as images on disk so they can be retrieved quickly.  The tiles are regenerated for different zoom levels so that more detail shows up at different levels.   Since lower zoom levels may have millions of tiles, but are rarely visited, those may be generated at viewing time, instead of being pre-generated.

Then they set up their applications (Javascript-based or otherwise), to request all the tiles over a given viewing area and zoom level, and piece the tiles together to generate a complete map.

[WMTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Map_Tile_Service) is one open standard for delivering map tiles over the web, although WMTS doesn't define the process for generating tiles.   [GeoWebCache](http://geowebcache.org/) is a service which, paired with a WMS server like [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/) or [MapServer](http://mapserver.org/), can be used for generating tiles from spatial data.

Answer (score -5):

You can check out [elasticsearch](http://elasticsearch.org/). Its an open source search engine extensively used for bigdata technologies. You can perfrom geospatial queries on top of huge data in elasticsearch with high efficiency.